# String values ​are not being loaded from Firestore

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm studying Kotlin + Firebase, and I'm facing a problem about loading String values.

I have a Firebase patch named "scheduling", and the values ​​"customer, employee, date and time".

The amount of submissions is being loaded correctly (I have 10 saves and 10 are loading), however, the values ​​are not displayed.

[image: Problem image]

I'm doing it like this:

Model data class:

```
data class User(var tvCustomer: String ?= null, var tvEmployee: String ?= null, var tvDate: String ?= null, var tvTime: String ?= null)
```

Layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCustomer"
>/

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvEmployee"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDate"    

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTime"
```

Adapter class:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val user : User = userList[position]
    holder.customer.text = user.tvCustomer
    holder.employee.text = user.tvEmployee
    holder.data.text = user.tvDate
    holder.hora.text = user.tvTime

}

class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val customer : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCustomer)
    val employee : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmployee)
    val date : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate)
    val time : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime)
}
```

DATA BASE:

```
'fun save(view: View, customer: String, employee: String, date: String, time: String) {

    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    val userMap = hashMapOf (
        "customer" to customer,
        "employee" to employee,
        "date" to date,
        "time" to time)

    db.collection("agendamento").document(cliente).set(userMap)
        .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
            mensagem(view, "Success!", "#FF03DAC5")
    }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
        mensagem(view, "Server error!", "#FF0000")
    }
}'

'private fun EventChangeListener() {

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    db.collection("agendamento")
        .addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{
            override fun onEvent(
                value: QuerySnapshot?,
                error: FirebaseFirestoreException?
            ) {

                if (error != null) {
                    Log.e("Firestore Error", error.message.toString())
                    return
                }

                for (dc : DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!) {
                    if (dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                        userArrayList.add(dc.document.toObject(User::class.java))

                    }
                }

                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

            }
        })

}'
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot see it.